# UL not centering inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a div element containing an unordered, inline list on a webpage.
I set the containing div's margins to auto auto, centering the div on the page correctly, but I can't find a way to get the inline list it contains to center properly within it. The inline list remains slightly to the left within the div. I tried to fix by putting:
padding: auto auto;
in the containing div element, so whatever text/lists it contained would be centered, but that doesn't have any effect...

I tried

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Exo-Black';
 src: url('fonts/Exo-Black.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceCodePro-Black';
    src: url('fonts/SourceCodePro-Black.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/Exo-Bold.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo-Regular';
    src: url('fonts/Exo-regular.otf');
}

.icon {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.name {
    font-family: Exo-Black;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: firebrick;
    width: 60%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.phone {
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
}

.nav {
    clear: left;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: SourceCodePro-Black;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: auto auto;
}

li { display: inline; }
```

**HTMLcode:**

```
 <div id="page">
  <div class="icon"> 
    <img src="pics/icon2.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="104" /> 
   </div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>Mount Vernon PC</p>
  </div>
  <div class="phone">
    <p>Call or Text: (555) 555 - 5555</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Infection</li>
      <li>Repair</li>
      <li>Upgrade</li>
      <li>Build</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: define .nav{margin:0 auto;}

Comment: i guess, u have closed extra divs..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6vLT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ul` element has a default left indention (`padding-left`) for markers not to be pushed out of the list :

```css
ul#navigation { padding-left: 0; text-align:center; list-style-type:none; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36gSf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/L7yWJ/

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

li {
    margin:10px;
    background:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add display:block in li and text-align:center in li element.
Also, by default ul takes padding from left so, you have to set it to 0.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Exo-Black';
 src: url('fonts/Exo-Black.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceCodePro-Black';
    src: url('fonts/SourceCodePro-Black.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/Exo-Bold.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo-Regular';
    src: url('fonts/Exo-regular.otf');
}

.icon {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.name {
    font-family: Exo-Black;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: firebrick;
    width: 60%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.phone {
    font-family: SourceSansPro-Bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
}

.nav {
    clear: left;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: SourceCodePro-Black;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: auto auto;
}

li { display: block; text-align:center;  }

ul { padding:0px; }
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/Y6vLT/3/